# Ensuring memory not leaking in UIWebView

Tags: ios, memory-management, uiwebview

I would like to know if I am using good memory management practise with UIWebView. My app makes extensive use of hundreds of local html files, which the user can get to at the end of a table hierarchy. The user can also swipe left and right for previous and next pages.

In viewDidLoad, I set everything up, such as background colour and gesture recognizers, and I add it to the view:

```
[self.view addSubview: self.myWebView];
```

Only in dealloc do I set the UIWebView's delegate to nil, and release it.

In viewWillAppear, I set the UIWebView's delegate to self, while in viewWillDisappear, I set the delegate to nil (as well as ask it to "stopLoading").

Each time I load a new document in, I use loadHTMLString:

```
[self.myWebView loadHTMLString:fullHTML baseURL:nil];
```

Is what I'm doing sufficient to keep the memory happy? Is this issue from [two years ago](https://devforums.apple.com/message/59030#59030) still relevant?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have written should not leak memory.  I don't know if the issue you linked to still happens, but I have not had problems with it in my use of UIWebView.

Comment: Well, by popular (non) vote, it appears the community agrees with you. My worries were unfounded, it seems. Thank you.

Comment: You could try running your project with the leaks tool to see if it is leaking memory, but as I said, based on the code you provided, you should not be leaking memory and if you are, it is not your fault.